# Python static variable resolution

Tags: python, static, static-variables

I am trying to create a counter of all instances created for a particular class.
It is clear that my code does not increment `self.__class__.counter` past 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
 class Feature(object):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.id = self.__class__.counter
        self.__class__.counter = self.__class__.counter + 1
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Feature: id=%d name=%s" % (self.id,self.name,)
```

**Update:**
This code actually works as intended. 
Smart folks left some very detailed explanations how statics are being handled in python. I voted to close my question, but hate if the answers will disappear.

Comment: Isn't your `counter` variable an instance attribute, that you can access on objects of `Feature` class? (I mean the one in the second line, directly after the class signature)

Comment: I can't see the behaviour you're explaining, can you show a runnable snippet with the wrong output?

Comment: This code works fine when I try it.

Comment: @RikPoggi +1 You are right. Somehow it works for me now too.

Comment: it was a case of 6pm coding. it works I will deleate this question as irrelevant in few minutes. Thank you very much, all.

Comment: You have not deleted your question, would you like it closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (though your code works fine for me, so I suspect it's not the code you're actually running to observe the problem).

```
class Feature(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Feature.counter
        Feature.counter += 1
```

You can replace `Feature` by `type(self)` (or `self.__class__`, same thing) if you prefer, but note that they'll behave differently in the presence of subclasses (maybe that's your problem, actually).

The rules for using class/instance variables are very simple in Python, and it helps to keep them in mind:

1. Reading the value of an attribute with `self.name` will fall back to the class of `self`, and then to the base class hierarchy if `self` does not directly contain an attribute named `name`.
2. Writing the value of an attribute with `self.name = ...` ***always*** binds `name` directly in `self`.

In particular, when writing a value it *does not matter* where a read to the same attribute would have gone before the assignment.

So if in your actual program you're instantiating a *subclass* of `Feature`, which I'll call `Sub` then this line:

```
self.__class__.counter = self.__class__.counter + 1
```

will probably not do what you expect. It will *read* from the `Feature.counter` (the first time you create an instance of `Sub`), but will *write* to `Sub.counter`. Thereafter the reads will go to `Sub.counter` (because it exists now), and so the `Sub` instances will get increasing ids, but they're not increasing the value of `Feature.counter`, so instances of other subclasses of `Feature` can get duplicate ids.

So I'd use `Feature.counter` if I was thinking of `counter` as a global variable living in the `Feature` namespace, and I wanted all the subclasses of `Feature` to share the same counter. I'd use `type(self).counter` if I expect each and every subclass of `Feature` to have its own independent counter (but then you'd need to do something to initialise them).

Comment: I discovered that I was looking at the different log. Code works. And its original idea to use it with subclasses as you've described. Thank you very much for the explanation anyway.

Comment: Bonus Question: Is it possible to create an abstract class that will be able to provide counters for all of its subclasses? Binary answer will do. :)

Comment: @bioffe Almost certainly. :) (whether you mean independent counters or a shared one)

Answer (score 1):

To better illustrate the differences between `self.__class__.attribute` and `ClassName.attribute`:

```
class Feature(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.__class__.counter
        self.__class__.counter += 1

class Sub(Feature):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()        

print [(vars(Feature()), vars(Sub())) for i in xrange(3)]
print Feature.counter, Sub.counter, id(Feature.counter) == id(Sub.counter)


class Feature(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Feature.counter
        Feature.counter += 1

class Sub(Feature):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()


print [(vars(Feature()), vars(Sub())) for i in xrange(3)]
print Feature.counter, Sub.counter, id(Feature.counter) == id(Sub.counter)

>>> [({'id': 0}, {'id': 1}), ({'id': 1}, {'id': 2}), ({'id': 2}, {'id': 3})]
3 4 False
>>> [({'id': 0}, {'id': 1}), ({'id': 2}, {'id': 3}), ({'id': 4}, {'id': 5})]
6 6 True
```

Comment: Good demo. But what happens if this class gets extended. Woudn't it be fair to assume that `self.__class__` will bind itself to the lowest in a class hierarchy?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with lowest. `__class__` will always be the actual class - the top of ypur hierachy - the type of your object. So if you use just call the `__init__` of the ancestor with super the `__class__` counter of the Subclass will be another object, but without `self.__class__` they will remain the same. So by using `Feature.counter` your subclasses will increment the parent's class counter either.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this paradigm so much more when trying to count instances:

```
from itertools import count

class MyClass():
  _getId = count(0).next
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = self._getId()
```

Comment: Absolutely love it. Glad to learn something new today. Need some time to process the mechanics though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the class name itself, like

```
self.id = Feature.counter
Feature.counter += 1
```

Comment: If your class is part of hierarchy, you can get finer control to which namespace your class variable will be placed to. Yours is hardcoded.

Comment: So, may be I do not understand all the concepts of Python so far. Does the object reference of `__class__` change in sub-classes? Better: does `__class__` point to the sub-class' class-object when `__class__` is used in the super-class?

Comment: I can reuse the same code, but yet have a separate counter for overloaded classes, provided there will be a separate class level counter variable.

Comment: @freakazoid_em `self.__class__` is just reading an attribute of `self`. No matter where you are when you evaluate it (a subclass method, a superclass method, some non-class code, or the interactive interpreter) what it gets depends only on `self`. So it always is the direct class of `self`, not any superclass.